# Visual notifications not working with Element app

Tags: plank, notifications

I installed the [Element](https://element.io/) messaging app on Elementary OS and there is no visual notifications when somebody writes a message, only the audio notifications work i.e. a sound is played when I receive a message.

On Ubuntu, it looks like this:

[image]

On Elementary OS there is no visual hint on whether you received a message or not in the dock or anywhere else:

[image]

I'm using `plank` as dock:

[image]

On other messaging apps such as Skype, there is a small red glowing dot underneath the icon when you have an unread message(the dot changes to blue when there are no unread messages).

Does anyone have any idea whether it is possible to have the same behavior for Element? Or if not, is it possible to have some kind of a visual hint when one has an unread message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this sometimes has to do with how the application presents notifications to the OS. Things like Telegram or Skype for instance, can display badge icons in the Dock or Applications menu similar to the way things like AppCenter can. The glowing dot you're seeing in Ubuntu is part of the AppIndicator/System Tray icon in the panel, but this is not reflective of what you might see in the Dock. Take a look at the Ubuntu Dock, for instance. Does the same app provide you with a matching badge for the app there as well? If not, then it's likely that the application is currently hardcoded with support only for typical system tray implementations.